# Bootstrap + AngularJS - How to sort/search/edit/pagination table columns

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

can someone show me an example of using Bootstrap and AngularJS to create table columns with

- sort
- search
- edit
- pagination

Comment: Check this example it will gives your the full understanding of CRUD (ANGULARJS+BOOTSTRAP+PHP) https://www.codeofaninja.com/2015/12/angularjs-crud-example-php.html

Comment: Just typing "angular bootstrap" in Google will give you gazillion of such examples, on the first line appears AngularUI, which is ... well, mostly Angular + Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code (instead of json data you can simply put your data directly in the table):

```
<table id="resultTable" 
    data-toggle="table" 
    data-url="json.php" 
    data-show-refresh="true" 
    data-show-toggle="true" 
    data-show-columns="true" 
    data-search="true" 
    data-select-item-name="toolbar1" 
    data-pagination="true">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id" data-align="right" data-sortable="true">Item ID</th>
      <th data-field="column1" data-sortable="true">Column1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

So what you look for is `data-search="true"` (search) and `data-pagination="true"` (pagination) as well as `data-sortable="true"` (sort).

For editing I think you need to use an additional plugin like this one: https://mindmup.github.io/editable-table/